# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte ... in position ... ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, scipy, ipython

I've read topics with the similar question, but none of it fits my problems. I'm working in iPython notebook and I have the following chunk of code:

```
import scipy as sp
%pylab inline
```

When I try to run it, it fails on second line with the error in the title. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the % before pylab i guess that you just have to define the encoding to utf8.

---

Like:

```
import sys  

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Comment: Seems like that was it, but not I'm getting - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cbook', on the same line, but nested when it comes to part - import matplotlib.cbook as cbook. Did you maybe work with scipy? I've downloaded anaconda and these are the problems I'm getting.

Comment: Try this one...

import matplotlib //
import matplotlib.cbook